# Its surveillance apparatus is (mostly) in order to monitor

Tags: to-infinitive

1. Its surveillance apparatus is (mostly) **to monitor** budget deficits in real time, but it could also help to evaluate the future consequences of policy decisions. (with or without "mostly")
2. This money was (mostly) **to tackle** youth unemployment. (with or without "mostly")

Q: Do they both mean (*infinitive of purpose*):

3. Its surveillance apparatus is (mostly) **in order to  monitor** budget deficits in real time, but it could also help to evaluate the future consequences of policy decisions. (with or without "mostly")
4. This money was (mostly) **in order to tackle** youth unemployment. (with or without "mostly")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say something *is for* this, or *is to do* that, you are expressly stating its purpose. Including "mostly" just indicates that the stated purpose is its main, or majority purpose, but that there are other purposes, too.

In your latter examples, you have used "in order" incorrectly. We might say that something was *done* in order to achieve a particular goal, but we don't use that in connection with an object. For example, you could say "the money was *spent* in order to...", or "the machine was *purchased* in order to...". But saying "the machine was in order" would normally mean that the machine was *in working order*.